# How to quickly remove FEN string in xskak

Tags: chess, xskak

I was wondering if there was a more time efficient way to remove the FEN string or keep it from the output pdf when using `xskak`?

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=20]{scrreprt}

% This is a LaTeX file generated by Scid.

% You must have the skak, KOMAScript and pstricks packages installed to typeset this file.


\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{charter}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{xskak}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage{tabularx}


% \definecolor{VariationColor}{gray}{0.40}

\definecolor{VariationColor}{RGB}{0,0,128}

% \definecolor{ScoreColor}{gray}{0.40}

\definecolor{ScoreColor}{RGB}{255,215,0}

\definecolor{GridColor}{RGB}{72,61,139}

\definecolor{EvenGameColor}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\definecolor{BlackPiecesGraphColor}{RGB}{101,37,37}

\definecolor{WhitePiecesGraphColor}{RGB}{189,183,107}


\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\newcommand{\win}{1-0}

\newcommand{\loss}{0-1}

\newcommand{\draw}{=-=}

\newcommand{\p}{\figsymbol{p}}

\newcommand{\N}{\figsymbol{N}}

\newcommand{\B}{\figsymbol{B}}

\newcommand{\R}{\figsymbol{R}}

\newcommand{\Q}{\figsymbol{Q}}

\newcommand{\K}{\figsymbol{K}}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{blue}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{red}}


\begin{document}

\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}

{

\center

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{rllXr}


White: & Abu Naim & & & ?\\

Black: & 9th Century & & & \\

& & & & ????\\

Result: & 1-0\\

\end{tabularx}

\\[1ex]}

\newchessgame


\hrulefill

\\

\end{@twocolumnfalse}

]

Fen: 6K1/3r3r/5kn1/5p2/5P2/6N1/8/4R1R1 w - - 0 1\\[1ex]

\newchessgame[moveid=1w,setfen=6K1/3r3r/5kn1/5p2/5P2/6N1/8/4R1R1 w - - 0 1]

\begin{center}

\vspace{1ex}

\chessboard

\vspace{1ex}

\end{center}

\mainline{1. Nh5+!!}


Decoy: g6\\[1ex]

\mainline{1... Rxh5 }

\begin{center}

\vspace{1ex}

\chessboard[lastmoveid,pgfstyle=border,color=gray,markfields={\xskakget{moveto},\xskakget{movefrom}},pgfstyle=straightmove,markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto}]\vspace{1ex}

\end{center}

\textcolor{VariationColor}{\variation{1... Rxh5 2. Rxg6+ }}

\\[1ex]

\mainline{2. Rxg6+!}


Decoy: g6\\[1ex]

\mainline{2... Kxg6 }

\begin{center}

\vspace{1ex}

\chessboard[lastmoveid,pgfstyle=border,color=gray,markfields={\xskakget{moveto},\xskakget{movefrom}},pgfstyle=straightmove,markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto}]\vspace{1ex}

\end{center}

\textcolor{VariationColor}{\variation{2... Kxg6 3. Re6\# }}

\\[1ex]

\mainline{3. Re6\# }


{\textbf 1-0}

\hrule


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Show a complete example.

Comment: Don't add examples as external links. Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: From page 18 of  the [documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xskak/xskak.pdf), add a line like FEN: \mbox{\xskakgetgame{lastfen}}

Comment: Don't add examples in a comment. Edit your question. And show a *complete* example, that can be compiled, not some snippet.

Comment: @Djp yes I read the documentation before asking the question and no that is not what I am trying to do. I am just trying to remove the fen string from showing on my output pdf.

Comment: Sorry. Thought that was a typo as I've used the package quite a bit years ago and have never seen a FEN string printed. If you post your minimal example it will be easier for someone to help you figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Well your file contains the FEN as text, there is nothing xskak can do about it, you will have to change the file manually or correct the export (the file also contains a lot of wrong \\ and other curious things).

Comment: Doesn't xskak use the that fen string to set up the board in the output? As for the "\\" scid puts in a lot of unnecessary bits so I have to edit its output and remove them. Besides that what other wrong items should I remove/edit? Thank you for your help Ulrike. I'm sorry about messing up the post...it is a bit difficult for me to juggle the code over to my phone to post it.

Comment: The fen after `setfen=` is used by xskak, but in the line above you have a fen that is simply printed.

Comment: Yes, of course, as it is automatically generated(incorrectly)from this program I am trying to stop it from being printed. Up to now I have manually removed them...this of course eats up valuable time. There must be a way to either remove the unwanted fen from output or I need to find a more efficient method.